# How to re-scale the vector so that the outline is equal to 5m

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have the image below, which is an outline vector image. I would like to resize the image, so that the total length of outline is 5 meters. Could somebody help me to fix this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Could you post the vector file?

Comment: Make bounding rectangle (of reindeer only) 784 * 1022 cm should make perimeter approx 5m

Comment: Can do it in mathematica, just need svg

Comment: "Could you post the vector file" -- we don't really do that around here @martin This stack isn't about altering files for users. Questions/answers should be relatable applicable to *any* file, not specific files. In addition, random file downloads can be a security risk for users. All intentions may be good, but there *will* be some malicious individual that takes advantage at some point.

Comment: @Scott yes, didn't think of that! I think your answer is more than adequate in any case!

Answer (score 5):

I *think* the best you can do is adjust with approximation and then readjust. There's no built in feature I'm aware of that will control the *length* of a multidirectional path - or allow one to adjust a multidirectional path numerically to adjust its length. It *might* be scriptable... hard to say.

Open the **Document Info Panel** (`Window > Document Info`).

From the *Panel Menu* choose `Objects` and select your shape. That will display the path's length.

From there, it's a matter of math to determine the amount of scaling required in order to change the path's length to a desired number.